# register service worker with http

Tags: service-worker

I am trying to register service worker in my project
but is is giving error as 
"Failed to register a ServiceWorker: An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script."

and i opened chrome with insecure using below command

/opt/google/chrome/chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/foo --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https:://localexample.com

after opening url in chrome insecure window it is still giving error as same in console like "Failed to register a ServiceWorker: An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script" and in terminal it is giving  error as "ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(918)] CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for localexample.com failed err=-8172".

Any solution ???

Comment: Try again, replacing `https:://localexample.com` replaced with `http://localexample.com`. Use one `:` instead of two, and use `http` instead of `https`, since the whole point is that you *can't* access localexample.com via https.

Answer (score 1):

open chrome in insecurity mode then you can install and implement service worker without using https:

Type below command in terminal (Ubuntu) :

$ /opt/google/chrome/chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/foo --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://example.com

Answer (score 0):

Right click on google chrome icon and open properties and change the target field in shortcut section to `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir=C:\dir --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=<your site url>"`.

[image]

Now when you launch chrome again the service worker will work.

Answer (score 0):

So I repeat mostly the answer from Nr.

If that specific DomException was happened locally, when accessing web resource at local machine with certificate, one of these latest version of browser launches may had helped:

```
open -a Opera.app --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/foo --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://localhost:8111

open -a Brave\ Browser.app --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/foo --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://localhost:8111

open -a Google\ Chrome.app --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/foo --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://localhost:8111
```

Chromium browser did not start with these settings to allow to overcome this specific DomException for using SSL with service worker locally.

This person provided some insights as a story as well for this matter: https://deanhume.com/testing-service-workers-locally-with-self-signed-certificates/